# How to have Input display each day of the week?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the code to ask the user to enter sale on sunday thru saturday, while adding it to the list.

When I do so, it says, "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" I'm not really too sure how to fix this with weekdays.

Thanks

```
    store_sales = []

    week_days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

    for sale in range(week_days):

        value = float(input('Enter sale amount for' + str(week_days) + ': '))

        store_sales.append(value)

        print(store_sales)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with this code and let us know how it goes ?

```
store_sales = []

week_days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

for sale in week_days:

    value = float(input('Enter sale amount for ' + sale + ': '))

    store_sales.append(value)

    print(store_sales)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing because `range` takes either a single integer, or exactly three integers, and results in a sequence of integers with even spacing. Please see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Like Gagan pointed out, you can just iterate through week_days directly, i.e. `for sale in week_days`.

You can also use the `calendar` module to avoid writing all the day names yourself.

```
import calendar
for day_name in calendar.day_name:
    value = ...
```

Comment: Yep, just tried the calendar and it works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you just have to loop over `week_days` list and that's it.

```
store_sales = []
week_days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
for week_day in week_days:
    value = float(input('Enter sale amount for {} :'.format(week_day)))
    store_sales.append(value)
    print(store_sales)
```

The other simple way is to use `calendar` module :

```
import calendar
for week_day in calender.day_name:
    value = float(input('Enter sale amount for {} :'.format(week_day)))
    store_sales.append(value)
    print(store_sales)
```

Comment: I tried with the calendar mode, and it works great! Thanks.

Comment: Upvoting is a great way to say thanks :D @TrevorNeal